# Pseudocode from python

Tags: python, pseudocode

I have a problem regarding what is the pseudocode of my python code.

My Python Code:

```
if seat[row][column] == "X " :
```

What is the pseudocode for my python code?

Comment: edited, i miss type @Zinki

Comment: You might have used a higher-level statement like "If the seat at [row] and [column]" is reserved". Personally, I find one of the joys of Python to be that it is so readable, I rarely  need pseudocode at all. Just code (including comments).

Answer (score 3):

"pseudocode" is not a set-in-stone language. You can't translate something to pseudocode, just like you can't translate something to gibberish.

"pseudocode" is a general term for a snippet that does not run in any existing language. It describes an idea rather than actual code that can be executed.

[Wikipedia's definition for psuedocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) says

> Pseudocode is an informal high-level description of the operating principle of a computer program or other algorithm. It uses the structural conventions of a normal programming language, but is intended for human reading rather than machine reading.

For what it's worth, a "valid" pseudocode for your code can be

```
if seat at row at column equals X:
```

Note that I wrote "valid", not "good".

Comment: @DeltaTroz My answer still holds.

Comment: Thank you Deepspace

Comment: umm, how about main_menu() , what is the valid pseudocode for that

Comment: That depends on what `main_menu()` does. It could be "Show the main menu".